# Symfony not returning POST-value

Tags: php, post, http-post, symfony

I'm trying to implement simple search form with Symfony and trying to access the POST-value inside the controller without success.

I have the following code inside the controller:

```
public function foodAction(Request $request)
{

    $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('keyword', SearchType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ruokahaku'), 'label' => false))
        ->add('search', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-secondary'), 'label' => 'Hae'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {  

        $searchName = $request->request->get('keyword');

        return $this->render(
            'default/index.html.twig',
            array('foodsearched' => $searchName,
            'form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

However the $searchName is always null, even when

```
var_dump($request->request->get('form'));
```

returns this:

```
array(3) { ["keyword"]=> string(6) "potato" ["search"]=> string(0) "" ["_token"]=> string(43) "2KIt0IYl3Ay-4vr-dEINKe3QNRxvMqmAFK1ILGflwoA" }
```

Which means the variable exists. However the $searchName stays NULL all the time.
This boggles me because this example is pretty much straigtforward from the Symfony book (version 3.1, pages 156 - 157). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve data (as an array) from the form using:

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

And if you want to retrieve a custom value, like `keyword`, try:

```
$keyword = $form->get('keyword')->getData();
```

Comment: This did the trick :) Thank you very much! I needed the custom value inside the controller because i'm using the keyword for searching stuff from the database.